# Why are the results different under debugging and running?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm solving a algorithm problem https://codeforces.com/contest/1671/problem/E. Although my submit can pass the tests provided by the contest, I find it fails on specific test(Hack). When I'm trying to find where's the error, I find that if I choose start debugging, the program would run perfectly. However, when I click "run", it would give a wrong answer. So, I'm curious about what happens.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;
int const NN = 1e6;
int const MOD = 998244353;
char str[NN];

long long dfs_data[NN];
int powans[20];
string myhash[NN];
int n;

long long dfs(int num) {
   if (dfs_data[num] != 0) return dfs_data[num];
   if (num >= powans[n - 1] - 1) {
       dfs_data[num] = 1;
       return 1;
   }
   if (myhash[num * 2 + 1] == myhash[num * 2 + 2]) {
       dfs_data[num] = (dfs(num * 2 + 1) % MOD) * (dfs(num * 2 + 2) % MOD) % MOD;
   } else dfs_data[num] = 2 * (dfs(num * 2 + 1) % MOD) * (dfs(num * 2 + 2) % MOD) % MOD;
   return dfs_data[num];
}

void gethashcode(int t) {

   if (t >= powans[n - 1] - 1) {
       myhash[t] += str[t];
       return;
   }
   if (myhash[2 * t + 1] == "") gethashcode(2 * t + 1);
   if (myhash[2 * t + 2] == "") gethashcode(2 * t + 2);
   if (myhash[2 * t + 1] < myhash[2 * t + 2]) myhash[t] = str[t] + myhash[2 * t + 1] + myhash[2 * t + 2];
   else myhash[t] = str[t] + myhash[2 * t + 2] + myhash[2 * t + 1];
}

void solve() {
   memset(dfs_data, 0, sizeof dfs_data);

   cin >> n;
   cin >> str;
   powans[0] = 1;
   for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++) {
       powans[i] = 2 * powans[i - 1];
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < NN; i++) {
       myhash[i] = "";
   }

   gethashcode(0);

   cout << dfs(0);
}

int main() {
   solve();
}
```

Comment: On a totally unrelated note, please don't use so-called "competition" or "online judge" sites to learn *anything*. Despite what some may claim, they are *not* any kind or teaching or learning resource, and using them as such might actually hinder your own learning process. All that seems to be taught by such sites are bad habits, bad code, and sometimes even invalid code. While your code doesn't seem to contain anything directly invalid, I see a lot of bad habits and bad code, including a total lack of bounds-checking.

Comment: Most likely the code is invoking undefined behavior somewhere.  Undefined behavior means anything can happen, including having the program behave differently depending on whether it is running within a debugger or not.

Comment: And what is the "good answer", and for which parameters?